# How to fetch data from database via Api

Tags: database, postgresql, flutter, dart

I created one Digital Vcard. when user enter details like, name , phone, email etc.. it generate qr code and sharing details via Digital Vcard. all the details going to store in DB via Api, I'm using postgres DB. when user entered details and submit the Id is generated for every entries and Data is store DB.

```
body: FutureBuilder(
    future: futureData,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: dataDetaisl.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                // height: 250,
                // width: 300,
                color: Color(0xFFCCF5FF),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10,vertical: 10),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text('Name : ${dataDetaisl[index].name}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black),),
                    Text('Role : ${dataDetaisl[index].role}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black),),
                    Text('Comapny : ${dataDetaisl[index].comapny}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    maxLines: 1,),
                    Text('Address : ${dataDetaisl[index].address}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black),
                      maxLines: 2,),
                    Text('Email : ${dataDetaisl[index].email}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black),),
                    Text('Phone : ${dataDetaisl[index].phone}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black),),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
        );
      }
      else{
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
      }
    }
  ),
);
```

---

```
Future<List<DataDetails>> getData() async {
final responce = await http.get(Uri.parse('Api url'));
var data = jsonDecode(responce.body.toString());

if(responce.statusCode == 200) {
  for(Map<String,dynamic> index in data) {
    dataDetaisl.add(DataDetails.fromJson(index));
  }
  return dataDetaisl;
} else {
  return dataDetaisl;
}
```

}

---

I want to Fetch the Data and Display in next page from Api's but for every new entries it generate new ID. I don't Know how to to store that generated ID and fetch the data by GetByID method. so please help and guide. if possible share example code. I followed up this method but i not able to fetch.
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Thank you.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you added more code to support your question. I also helps us understand your thought process.

Comment: @Davis get method and model link added please check

Comment: When you create a new record on Postgres, you should capture the id on the backend and return it in the POST response body. I don't know what backend framework you use but it should be pretty straightforward to get the id after you create the record. Then you can pass that id to the next page and fetch the data with that it.

Comment: @frenzy_funky yeah correct, this is issue I'm facing, but I don't know how to do because I'm new to Flutter. If possible please share Example code. Thank you

Comment: @Nihar Sorry, I couldn't understand the flow by looking at your code snippets. Why do you have a list of items inside the detail view? Don't you want to show single item for an id after you create an entity on the previous page?

Comment: Hi @Nihar, Try to generate the id manually so that when the id is created you can store your data with this id in database and you can also store it in your qr. Now next time when you scan the qr code you will get the id and based on that id you can your data.

Comment: Hi @Aks, thank you so much, now I am getting data From DB but facing one issues not able to generate Qrcode for that data.

Comment: What's the error ? and what's the type of data you want to create the qr?

Comment: Hi @Aks I solved those errors,  I have one Doubt - it is possible, can I save/store multiple cards data in flutter? ( for eg: I want to create one Business card and another one professional card in both cards email, phone, role is different so can I store these multiple cards in flutter? ) Please help Thank you

Comment: Hi @Nihar You need to save/store in local database?

Comment: @Aks I'm saving data in DB. but I want to hold multiple cards with data, I'm fetching data from Api's

Comment: you can create 2 collections. 1st for card one, 2nd for card two. for example: user1 is having 2 collections, and when you are fetching data from your db you will get the both collections and then you can do whatever you want to with that data

Comment: Hi @Aks I posted a new Question regarding Edit and Update please check and help. Thank you

Comment: @Nihar please add the link for that question here.

Comment: @Aks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76041523/i-want-to-update-my-db-data-from-user-input-text-field/76042023#76042023