# I want to update my DB data from user Input text field

Tags: flutter, dart, get, put

I want to update data by Id, I have userId, name and all details, if I want to change any user details based on user Id so I'm not able to update data and I am getting values above the Text Form Field. please check my update data function and code and help, I am new to flutter.

```
Future<DataDetails> getDataa() async {
final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse("get url"));
if(response.statusCode == 200) {
  var temp = DataDetails.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  return temp;
}
return DataDetails.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)) ;
}

 Future<DataDetails> updateData(String cardName,String name,String designation,String 
 company,String address,String email,String phone) async {

var edata = {
  "id": '$id',
  "cardName": cardName,
  "name": name,
  "designation": designation,
  "company": company,
  "address": address,
  "email": email,
  "phone": phone,
};
var ebody = jsonEncode(edata);
final response = await http.put(
    Uri.parse('put url'),
  body: ebody,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
  }
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {  
  return DataDetails.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
}
else {
 throw Exception('Failed to update Data.');
}
}
```

above code is getting value from DB and update.

this code I enter new value for update in DB, but in this code I'm not getting old values inside the Text form Field.

```
//initState 

 late Future<DataDetails> _futureData;

 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 _futureData = getDataa();
 }
  
 FutureBuilder(
          future: _futureData,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text('${snapshot.data!.cardName}'),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: _cardnameController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                         hintText: 'Enter Card Name',
                          border: OutlineInputBorder()
                      ),
                    ),
//Update button call:
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
              _futureData = updateData(
              _cardnameController.text,
              _nameController.text,
              _roleController.text,
              _companyController.text,
              _addressController.text,
              _phoneController.text,
              _emailController.text,
             );
         });
       },
         child: Text('Update'),
      ),
```

I'm new to Flutter Please help,
thank you

Comment: Try this `_cardnameController..text=cardName`. Otherwise you need to call API into `initState` and give value to the controller.

Comment: "I'm not getting old values inside the Text form Field." which code do you think does it? Because I see no code putting anything into the form field. Maybe you missed to post it?

Comment: Hi @HarshSureja I tried initState but its not working If possible please share one Example code for edit and update functions.

Comment: Hi @nvoigt may be I missed some where I dont know where I did mistake. so please guide and suggest example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _futureData,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        final data = snapshot.data as DataDetails;

        //update the text of controller here
        _controller.text = data.name;

        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(data.id.toString()),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                     hintText: 'Enter Card Name',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()
                  ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }
      return const Center(
        child: Text("Loading data..."),
      );
    },
  )
```

Comment: Hi, @Aks thank you so much its Working , I am getting data inside the Text form field but after Editing the data new value not update to DB. can you please check my update function? I will add update button function code also please help

Comment: sure. just show your code

Comment: added , update button and initState code.

Comment: what's your _futureData type?

Comment: Hi @Aks, I solved that issue now its working fine with your code after Editing Data updating in DB. Thank you so much sir for your Help and guidance

Comment: @Ask ,I have 1 more doubt : how to set or create user profile only one time when application launch first time after installation.

Comment: It's simple. Save a value in local db. based on that value you can navigate to registration page or home page. First time the registration form is filled then save a value in local db. Then next time when the app is started get that stored value, and navigate to homePage.

Comment: Hi @Aks Thanks its working. one more doubt : I want to fetch and display the data from api. I am using future builder and ListView builder  method. in this I am getting only one record , in database 3 records available its only displaying last one. if more then 3 records its showing blank page .. if I make  shrinkWrap: true, that 1 record is visible and  shrinkWrap: false, again  its showing  blank page like empty. I am stuck here from last 2 days please help

Comment: @Nihar you should post another question regarding this.

Comment: Hi @aks , question posted please check and help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76127108/how-to-display-multiple-card-data-from-api-in-flutter

Comment: Hi @Aks, I am facing one issue on pub get failed exit code: 65 after updating flutter ,  I posted question please check and help link is -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76163053/failed-flutter-pub-get-exit-code65-and-failed-parsing-lock-file

Answer (score 0):

As per the description of yours, that value is not showing in `TextFormField`. `Value` in `TextFormField` is managed through the controller, so just initialize the value in `initstate` as:

```
_cardnameController.text=cardname.toString;
```

Comment: yes its working now after Aks code. but after editing new value is not updating in DB. it showing "loading Data..." from Code .