# how to display multiple card data from api in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-listview

I want to fetch and display multiple records from DB via Api based on phone number. but I am getting only last record data. if record 1 available is it will display record 1, then add record 2 it will display record 2 in below the record 1 but record 1 is not visible it will show white blank page. when I add more then 3 records its showing Empty white blank page and also In list view builder shrinkWrap: true, then it displaying that last record or shrinkWrap: false, its showing empty blank page. Please check code and help

// get method

```
List<DataDetails> multiCardData=[];

Future<List<DataDetails>> getData() async {
sp_savedId = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
setState(() {
  get_savedId = sp_savedId.getString("Key_1").toString();
});
sp_savedPhone = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
setState(() {
  get_savedPhone = sp_savedPhone.getString("Key_2").toString();
});
id = get_savedId;
phone = get_savedPhone;
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('get url'));
var temp = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
if(response.statusCode == 200) {
   for(var userData in temp['data']) {
     var cardData = DataDetails();
     cardData.cardName = userData['cardName'].toString();
     cardData.id = userData['$id'];
     cardData.name = userData['name'].toString();
     cardData.designation = userData['designation'].toString();
     cardData.company = userData['company'].toString();
     cardData.address = userData['address'].toString();
     cardData.email = userData['email'].toString();
     cardData.phone = userData['phone'].toString();
     cardData.profilePhotoPath = userData['profilePhotoPath'].toString();
     cardData.qrCode =
     'BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0;\nN:${cardData.name};\nORG:${cardData
         .company}\nTITLE:${cardData.designation}\nADR:${cardData
         .address};;;;;;\nTEL;CELL:${cardData.phone}\nEMAIL:${cardData
         .email}\nEND:VCARD';
     multiCardData.add(cardData);
     print(multiCardData);
   }
   return multiCardData;
  } else {
  return multiCardData;
}
}
```

// display code:

```
 FutureBuilder(
              future: _futureBuilderData,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  // listview builder added...... check..
                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: multiCardData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Screenshot(
                        controller: _ssController,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OntapView()));
                          },
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [

                              Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                   //height: 130,
                                width: 350,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                    // color: Colors.amber[100]
                                    color: const Color(0xffccf7ff)
                                ),
                                child:  Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                      child: Row(
                                        //    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            height: 15,
                                            width: 200,

                                            child: Text('${multiCardData[index].cardName} ',
                                              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                          ),

                                          SizedBox(width: 20),
                                          Container(
                                            height: 20,
                                            width: 90,
                                            child: Image.asset('asset/image.png'),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 8),
                                    Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        CircleAvatar(
                                          radius: 45,
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage('image url'),
                                        //  FileImage(File('${multiCardData[index].profilePhotoPath}')),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                        Container(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,top: 10),
                                            width: 130,
                                            height: 100,
                                            child: Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                Text('${multiCardData[index].name} ',
                                                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                                const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                                Container(
                                                  child: Text('${multiCardData[index].designation}',
                                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            )
                                        ),

                                        const SizedBox(width: 60),
                                        Container(
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.08,
                                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.08,

                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                color: Colors.blue[600]
                                            ),
                                            child: IconButton(
                                              onPressed: () async {
                                                final list = await _ssController.capture();
                                                if (list != null) {
                                                  final directory = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
                                                  File imgFile = File(
                                                      '$directory/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png');
                                                  imgFile.writeAsBytesSync(list);

                                                  await Share.shareFiles([imgFile.path],text: 'Hi this is from qr code').catchError((e) {
                                                    debugPrint('Error: $e');
                                                  });
                                                }
                                              },
                                              icon: const Icon(Icons.share,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                size: 18,),
                                            ))
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    // const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                    Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            height: 60,
                                            width: 200,
                                            child:  Column(
                                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                              children:  [
                                                Text('Mob   : +91 -${multiCardData[index].phone}'),
                                                Text('Email : ${multiCardData[index].email} '),
                                                Text('Work  : ${multiCardData[index].company} ')
                                              ],
                                            ),

                                          ),


                                          const SizedBox(width: 20),

                                          ClipRRect(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                            child: Container(
                                              height: 90,
                                              width: 90,
                                              // color: Color(0xffFF0E58),
                                              child: QrImage(
                                                data: '${snapshot.data![index].qrCode}',
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          )

                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  );
```

Please check and help

Answer (score 0):

```
    class MyTest extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: FutureBuilder(
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 20,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return TestingListItem(index: '$index');
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
            future: Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), (){}),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

class TestingListItem extends StatelessWidget {

  String? index;
  TestingListItem({Key? key, this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.loose,
      children: [
        Card(
          elevation: 5,
          color: const Color(0xffccf7ff),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(flex: 70, child: Text('$index ', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),),
                      const SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 30,
                        child: Image.asset('asset/image.png'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 45,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage('image url'),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,top: 10),
                          width: 130,
                          height: 100,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text('$index name',
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5),
                              Container(
                                child: Text('$index designation',
                                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 60),
                    Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.08,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.08,

                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: Colors.blue[600]
                        ),
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () async {

                          },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.share,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 18,),
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 80,
                        child:  Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children:  [
                            Text('Mob   : +91 -$index phone'),
                            Text('Email : $index email'),
                            Text('Work  : $index company')
                          ],
                        ),

                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 20,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                          child: Container(
                              height: 90,
                              width: 90,
                              child: Container()
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

*When using Row try to avoid fixed height width*