# failed flutter pub get, exit code:65 / and Failed parsing lock file:

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Consider deleting the file and running `flutter pub get` to recreate it.
pub get failed

```
command: "C:\Android Studio\flutter_windows\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "C:\Android Studio\flutter_windows\flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\AAAa\aaaaa\Local\Pub\Cache",
}

exit code: 65
```

I'm facing this issue after updating flutter, Please help to solve this issue. I'm using Android Studio
Thank you

Comment: try - flutter pub cache repair

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: may be the caches are not updating. 1. try to download flutter latest version manually as zip file. then replace your flutter folder in LocalDisk-C with extract flutter folder of the downloaded zip. 2. If still not working you can install FVM which is used to handle multiple flutter versions in a machine. so you can use previous flutter version

Comment: Hi, @Aks I posted one new question can you please check  and help  me, I am facing issues, question link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76737786/screens-varies-design-and-widgets-size-also-varies-in-other-android-mobiles